# getting the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I keep getting the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined

```js
const messageChannel = cheese.channel.cache.get("796750832305307719");
```

Here's my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, Intents, Guild, channels } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
const cron = require('node-cron');
const express = require('express');
require('dotenv').config;

const channel = require('discord.js')
const { TextChannel } = require('discord.js')
const cheese = client.guilds.cache.get("796750832305307716");
const messageChannel = cheese.channel.cache.get("796750832305307719");
try {

app = express();

cron.schedule('* 24 18 * * *', function() {
    client.login('token').then(() =>{
        console.log("I am ready");
        messageChannel.send("TEST").then(() => client.destroy());
    })     
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Is your guild id correct? And have you already tried `client.guilds.fetch("guild id")`?

Comment: Is your client logged in at the time?

Comment: my client is logged in, and the guild-id is correct, i checked it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Well I see 2 problems in your code so I'll start from the top.

The error [`TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError) means that what's behind the object `chesse` is [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined).
So maybe your guild id in

```js
const cheese = client.guilds.cache.get("796750832305307716");
```

is incorrect. Try copying your guild id again (if it's still the same id maybe your bot isn't on the server you're targeting)`

Also change `channel` to `channels` in

```js
const messageChannel = cheese.channel.cache.get("796750832305307719");
```

You're searching between multiple channels so it's on plural if I'm not mistaken